# PHP proc_open to call program and get a screenshot

Tags: php

I'm trying to run a process to take a screenshot of a webpage in PHP using this cool software (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_site_screenshot.html)

This command works on windows command line and creates a .png file of the website:

```
C:\Program Files\SiteShoter>SiteShoter.exe /URL http://www.msn.com /Filename "C:\wamp64\www\my-site\test.png" /BrowserAutoSize 1 /MaxBrowserHeight 25000 MaxBrowserWidth 1500 /BrowserTimeOut 2000
```

I don't understand how to use proc_open to call the same command in a script. Here's what I've tried but without success:

```
$cmd     = "SiteShoter.exe /URL http://www.msn.com /Filename 'C:\wamp64\www\my-site\test.png' /BrowserAutoSize 1 /MaxBrowserHeight 25000 MaxBrowserWidth 1500 /BrowserTimeOut 2000";
$desc    = [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['pipe', 'w']]; //I don't know if this is needed
$cwd     = 'C:\Program Files\SiteShoter';
$process = proc_open($cmd, $desc, $pipes, $cwd);
```

The file is not created when the script is ran. Any ideas about what I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be filename parameter formatting and escaping some double quotes because the command line program is pick about its arguments.

```
$url = "http://www.msn.com";
$output_path = "c:/wamp64/www/my-site/";

$cmd     = "SiteShoter.exe /URL \"" . $url . "\" /Filename " . $output_path . "test-%date:yyyy-MM-dd%@%time:HHmm%.png /BrowserAutoSize 1 /MaxBrowserHeight 25000 MaxBrowserWidth 1500 /BrowserTimeOut 2000";
$descriptorspec = array();
$cwd = 'C:\Program Files\SiteShoter';
$env = NULL;

if ( $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env) ) {
    proc_close($process);
}
```

Anyhow if anyone is looking for a good program to capture an image of a webpage, I recommend SiteShoter from NirSoft.